# Gentry-Halevi’s Fully-Homomorphic Encryption and hermite factor

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

In section 7.2, page 18 in [Chen-Nguyen paper regarding BKZ 2.0](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2011/70730001/70730001.pdf#page=18), they point out different Hermite factors related to Gentry-Halevi FHE.

More precisely, it is said that the critical Hermite factor for the "large" challenge with lattice dimension $n=32768$ is $\delta = 1.0081^n$.

How is this Hermite factor computed ?

Comment: I think it has the following meaning. Each column corresponds to a specific challenge of Gentry-Halevi’s main challenges. You have to find the specific challenge (the links of the challenges are dead) and then calculate $||{\bf b}_1||/vol(L)^{1/n}.$ Then write it in the form $\delta^{n}.$  This form is useful, because many experiments have been made with different algorithms, and  for the specific challenge, BKZ-130 (experimentally) outputs a basis with $\delta^n$ Hermite factor.

Answer (score 1):

It is computed like that:
L is lattice with dimension i. B is BKZ reduction of lattice L.

$$Root Hermite Factor=( B[0].norm() / ( L.volume() )^{(1/i)})^{(1/i)}$$

If you want to calculate RHF, you can use [Sage Math](http://www.sagemath.org/).

Comment: Can you comment on which commands of Sage be useful?